# Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite) update failing after being forcefully terminated

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to update Eclipse/Spring Tool Suite to the latest version, but am getting this error:

> ```
> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
> Software currently installed: Spring Tool Suite 3.9.0.201707061903-RELEASE-e46 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.9.0.201707061903-RELEASE-e46)
> Missing requirement: Mylyn WikiText 3.0.13.20170711133400 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext 3.0.13.20170711133400)
>   requires 'package org.jsoup [1.7.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
> From: Mylyn WikiText Editors 3.0.13.201707111735 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.editors_feature.feature.group 3.0.13.201707111735)
> To: org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext [3.0.13.20170711133400]
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
> From: Mylyn WikiText 3.0.13.201707111735 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group 3.0.13.201707111735)
> To: org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.editors_feature.feature.group [3.0.13.201707111735]
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
> From: Spring Tool Suite 3.9.0.201707061903-RELEASE-e46 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.9.0.201707061903-RELEASE-e46)
> To: org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group [3.9.0.201707061903-RELEASE-e46]
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
> From: Spring Tool Suite Package 3.9.0.201707061903-RELEASE-e46 (org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group 3.9.0.201707061903-RELEASE-e46)
> To: org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group 0.0.0
> OK
> ```

I had previously terminated it forcefully (the process) because it was frozen/not responding after another update was running (it was running in the background as I worked and then everything just froze; so I terminated and restarted Eclipse and got back to work). Now any update I try fails with this error.

Is there a way to "clean up" the folder and make it go back to a working state? I've tried looking at the `.metadata` folder, `.snap` file, but have had no success. I also tried reloading the Mylin repository in the Available Update Sites section of the Eclipse Preferences.

Comment: you can try to go to the Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Update Sites and press "reload" for the relevant ones. That cleans up the cached data in case something is broken and caused a stale cache data entry.

Comment: I have the same problem, just trying to take the update, nothing out of the ordinary. [Eclipse Bug 492707](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=492707) seems related.

Comment: @MartinLippert But I'm not sure which ones would be the "relevant" ones. I tried to reload all the software sources but it still gave me this error. I ended up just reinstalling from scratch (fortunately the workspace settings were OK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to update an existing Eclipse/STS installation to a maybe newer STS version for a different Eclipse base platform version - which doesn't work and should not be done. You should always keep using the base Eclipse version and the corresponding update site when updating an existing Eclipse/STS installation.

For example, if you have STS 3.8.4 on Eclipse Neon.3 installed, you should continue to use the main STS update site for Eclipse 4.6 to update to newer STS versions: http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.6/. In that case, also take care that the main Eclipse update repo (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon) is configured and active in your preferences, since some components for the STS installation might be fetched from that update site (STS requires some bundles/components that are part of the Eclipse release train, but not always pre-installed in every Eclipse package that you downloaded - in case you started with Eclipse and added STS plugins to it).

If you downloaded the STS distribution from http://spring.io/tools, you have that update site already configured in your STS installation. And you can continue to use that for updating to STS 3.9.0, for example. This will update the STS components to version 3.9.0, but it WILL NOT update your base Eclipse IDE to Eclipse Oxygen (4.7). Your base Eclipse version will remain to be Neon.3.

If you want to upgrade to Eclipse Oxygen as your main IDE, you should download a fresh STS 3.9.0 for Eclipse Oxygen distribution and start to use that fresh install.

The same applies to older versions. Maybe you have Eclipse Mars (4.5) running (enhanced with STS components or from an STS distro itself), and you are trying to install or update to Eclipse 3.9.0 for Eclipse 4.6 now. This is not recommended and will most probably not work. Please do not add STS update sites for newer Eclipse versions to your existing STS installation.

Hope this explains the details and helps!!!

Comment: This makes good sense, but I didn't add STS update sites for newer Eclipse versions. I started out with an STS that was obtained from spring.io/tools (at version 3.7.4) and have updated it fine without any problems, but this last update to version 3.9 was what broke it.  I think you're right about the version of the base Eclipse though, everything does look a _bit_ different (and it upgraded my workspace and said it would no longer be compatible with previous versions). Probably some plugin or something went crazy. In any case, thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: If you started with STS 3.7.3 (there was no 3.7.4 released), you probably downloaded it for Eclipse 4.5 (that was the version that was on the spring.io/tools page around that time). And we provided updates for that version up to STS 3.8.4. (we always provide updates for the latest Eclipse release and the previous one). But there is no STS 3.9.0 version available that was built for Eclipse 4.5. So it looks like somehow the update site for STS on Eclipse 4.6 sneaked into your installation and now tries to update on your Eclipse 4.5-based STS install.

Comment: In case you would like to use STS 3.9.0, I would recommend to start with a fresh STS 3.9.0 distribution. That way you get the latest Eclipse Oxygen release automatically, too - which might be a good idea anyway... :-)

Comment: If you want to further investigate your old installation, you can take a look at the available updates sites in your preferences and check which one of the Eclipse update sites is there (releases/mars, releases/neon, etc.). I hope that there is only one which never changed. That gives you an indication which base Eclipse platform you started with. In addition to that you could take a look at the installation details (via the About dialog) and look for the plugin with ID "org.eclipse.platform" - just in case you would like to do further investigations on this.

Comment: You are correct! I mistyped the STS version number (I started at 3.7.3). I'm thinking that perhaps some plugin was the culprit... I'll just keep going with my fresh installation then. Thanks again for the detailed explanation!